# What software can I use to control / remote desktop a raspberry pi from windows

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, raspberry-pi

It is getting tiresome to **switch HDMI connectors** on one of my monitors between my windows desktop and raspberry pi.  It also confuses Windows.

I am looking for something like TeamViewer, so that I can remote into the **PI** from **Windows**

There is [this post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39119/remote-desktop-software-from-windows-to-linux-for-real-remote-sessions-not-just) but it's for multi-user access.  I just need single-user access.

And I can use **putty** to SSH in, I would prefer to see the GUI desktop on the Pi.

Is there something available that will let me do this

- Single User access
- Support for GUI
- Window on Windows must be resizable
- Free or low one-off cost

Comment: There are multiple ways depending on what fits best your need. You could set-up a VNC server on the Pi or simply install and X-server on your Windows machine and then export your display through ssh to Windows and  display GUI applications running on the Pi on Windows.

Comment: As you write you can use Putty (SSH), and you'd like something graphical, I assume you have X set up there – so you'd simply need a pendant to that on your Windows machine. You didn't write anything about license and price, hence just a few pointers: Mobatek's [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) includes what you need (an X server, see ![here](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/img/moba/home/xterm_xserver.png). There's also [Xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/), and probably some more.

Comment: For setting up and configure Raspberry Pi i had read a blog which is describing each and every step to be done. I guess it would help you. [Raspberry Pi to laptop](https://blog.guruface.com/configure-raspberry-pi-to-laptop-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

I used [TightVNC](https://www.tightvnc.com/) on my Pis*

It is free (gratis), has full remote desktop access and file transfer and a bunch of other features - read the full website.

If it's just a matter of

> It is getting tiresome to switch HDMI connectors on one of my monitors between my windows desktop and raspberry pi. It also confuses Windows.

then for a few dollars you could get an [AB box](https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=AS_20221112020311&SearchText=hdmi+ab+switch&spm=a2g0o.home.1000002.0) for a hardware solution.

---

(*) before I realised that my projects don't need an o/s and Linux was just getting in the way, so I switched to ESP32.